# AVAudioPlayer continues to play song after I delete it from resource bundle in iOS

Tags: ios, caching, avaudioplayer

```
-(void)loadSong
{
    NSString *song = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"nintendoMusic" ofType:@"mp3"];
    self.musicPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURLfileURLWithPath:song] error:NULL];
    [self.musicPlayer play];
}
```

This loads and plays the  file "nintendoMusic.mp3".   For some reason, though, if I delete the file "nintendoMusic.mp3" from the resource bundle, this code continues to work. Even when I reset the iOS simulator, it continues to work, and it plays the song.  Do you know why this is?

Comment: did you try to make Clean?

Comment: No but I just did and it didn't work.

Comment: what if you launch the app on a device? is it still playing?

Comment: also try to clean the build folder. Cmd-Alt-Shift-K

Comment: hmm that didn't seem to work either

Comment: i don't have a device at the moment.  When i loaded a new song into the resource bundle, and gave it the same name, the code then played the new song.  But when i deleted it, it did the same thing again.  Must just be a wonky ios simulator thing

Answer (score 3):

Try to remove this song from `Copy Bundle resource`

like

[image]